# Excel Item/Price Table Selection

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sheets one with a price table and other with a list on items I input.

I want a 2 table only with the items i actually used from the table, how could i generate that?

Check the screenshot i think it might be easier to understand.[image]

[image]

The input is in yellow. The price is auto calculated with the quantity. I just need a second table showing what was actually priced in. Any ideas?

Comment: They are kinda recursive, i just want the second table so i can update the prices that matter later.

Comment: Sounds like you want to apply an Advaced Filter

Comment: It will matter a lot whether you are using Excel O365.  What version are you running?

Comment: COPY the items from Input and VLOOKUP from Table 1??

Comment: @Max I'm using the latest version O365

Comment: @Lee Currently i have a couple of worksheets that are all linked to one price table worksheet. I would have  to go trough each sheet or change the structure entirely.

Comment: This will be easy to do.  A couple of questions…  (a) do you need the results to be in excel tables, or just in cells?  Also, the way you have your result, each item is in the same place in Table2 as it was in Table1.  Do you want it that way?  or do you want it so that if you *only* sold Bananas, that would be at the top of the list?

Comment: @Max It doesn't matter for me how the results are show or the position on the list.
I just need a list of items that were actually "inputed/sold". You might say why don't i copy the input list but the problem is - i have multiple worksheet tabs with multiple input list all receiving the price from one price worksheet and i want to clear the price table list of unused items.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Formulae solution: Generate the table using e.g. `=IF(F3 <> "", VLOOKUP(F3, table1, 2, FALSE), "")`
2. Power query merge tables (plenty of tutorials on youtube e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73T7isNVH_w)
3. Advanced filter (as suggested by @gns100), which would be my preferred solution in this case.

To implement #3 Advanced Filter, its worth reading the Microsoft help file as it can be tricky to set up. Here are a few tips:

1. Put your cursor any where in the price table (table 1) and click "Advanced" under the "Sort & Filter" section on the "Data" ribbon.
2. Set the settings as per image to duplicate to a new range and output to a single cell (which will spill and include headers)
3. Do not include any blank rows in your criteria range or it will filter incorrectly - this is especially important when updating the input with perhaps fewer lines, then re-doing the Advanced filter, as Excel remembers the previous settings.

[image]